# How to set parameters for specific processes window?

Tags: c#

So the plot is, for example, when I'm pressing some button on the form there should be 4 firefox browser windows appear on the screen, each window have specific own parameters, like x, y position, width, height and showed url.

So we decide to create 4 `backgroundWorker`'s that each will call a method for showing firefox browser window. Each `backgroundWorker` calls `Monitor_start_Firefox` method, that looks like this:

```
    public bool Monitor_start_Firefox(ref System.Diagnostics.Process process, string url, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Form1.FIREFOX_ADRESS;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " -new-window ";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments += url;

        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Form1.DebugWrite(0, "ProcessStartに失敗しました");
            Form1.DebugWrite(0, er.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        process.WaitForInputIdle();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Form1.DebugWrite(2, "MoveWindow Start:" + i.ToString());

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            bool find_flag = false;

            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length != 0)
                {
                    Form1.DebugWrite(2, "Process: " + p.ProcessName);
                    if (p.ProcessName == "firefox")
                    {
                        find_flag = true;
                        MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, x, y, w, h, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (find_flag == false)
            {
                //...
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This method actually works, 4 browser windows appear on the screen BUT the parameters of this screen like x, y, width and height completely random. I mean for example 2nd window can have positions of 3rd, or 1st window can have width and height of 4th. Sometime same window can be set two times, for example 3rd window at first can received parameters of 3rd window and then parameters of the 2nd window, and 2nd window not receive parameters at all. I guess it's because we using `backgroundWorker` and because it's assync it's not have strict order of setting parameters and we did something wrong with `MoveWindow` method.

At first I thought I could try to search specific process by `ID` and then strictly set it's own parameters, but turns out when I'm doing `process.Start`, process have completely different ID and not appear at `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` at all.
I also thought maybe I can directly call `process.MoveWindow()`, right after `process.Start`, but `process.HasExited` is also always `True` in my case, so when I'm trying to call `process.MoveWindow()` I have exception that saying that process already been exited. I read that it's always like this when we have assync.

So how can I strictly set specific parameter for specific browser window?
Can you please recommend me something? Thank you!

Comment: Let's take a look at the code.. I assume you call this code 4 times? So you start firefox.. And then you try up to 10 times to find any window with "firefox" as its owning process, including firefoxes that the user may have started before running your program.. and you move them.. And the problem is that random windows move... I think you'll need to completely re-engineer this

Comment: @CaiusJard that`s true, I call this method 4 times, for each browser window. About previous opened firefox windows, I forgot to mention, this program check for previously opened firefox windows, and ask to close them before we will start. So in this method in the loop we operate only with firefox windows that we opened during session. 
About the code, I understand you, I realise that I did something wrong with code quality, but just don't know from which side I should start to dig :/

Comment: @CaiusJard honestly I wish to completely change core of the program and logics, but just I celled inside task and just need to make hot fix of previous programmer. So I thought maybe I could change only this method instead of all logic.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that prevents the "look for a window owned by a process whose name is Firefox" from picking the same window 4 times. Does it have to be Firefox? If so seems you can specify location in other ways https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238607 and if it doesn't have to be Firefox I could give you some code that would open a Chromium browser window in a specific size and location.

Comment: If you're sticking with this method You could also try copypasting the Firefox exe 4 times and each time you launch start a different exe name and then each time you look, use a different exe name.. or use the command line options that tell Firefox not to reuse browser windows (probably why your process you started is exiting?) so the process you start can be used to derive the main window handle. Probably a bit of a nuisance these days because browsers tend to run several processes even for only one visible window